# Javascript code to display to pictures in one row

Tags: javascript, css, django, carousel

I have a javascript code for website and I need the two pictures array to show in one row. I have tried the css flex but that not how we want them to appear

are we able to join two pictures in javascript?

```
slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "inline-block";
slides[slideIndex].style.display = "inline-block";
```

I have tried css flex but since they are scrollable items they move all over the place and we only want them at the center. tried adding a parent class to arrange them in column css but didnt work

Comment: It's not very easy to picture how you want your image. Please create a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) which shows the problem. If you could visualise how you want your image to be in a row, then that would help as well.

Comment: If you dont want it to scroll all over the place, you could use the scroll snap behavior with css